# Identifying poles of $\cot(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

$\cot(z)=\dfrac{\cos z}{\sin z}$ and I am supposed to find poles at $z=k\pi \quad k=0,\pm1,\pm2... $. But derivative of $\dfrac{d}{dz}\cot(z)=-{\csc}^2(x)$ and it is also singular at $z=k\pi$. So why do we identify poles of cot(z) as simple poles but not essential singularities?

Do you have any suggestions for reading on this topic ?

Comment: Those poles correspond to the zeros of the denominator function $\sin z$. Does that fact tell you anything?

Comment: I can find residues at those points by simply taking limits at those points with corresponding z but I still do not understand why a function with unidentified derivatives have simple poles.

Comment: Can you think of a function that has a simple pole and the derivative *is* defined at that point? What's the derivative of $1/z$ at $z=0$?

Comment: Ok so for a function to be not singular it has to have continuous derivatives at that point yet it does not give us an idea about type of singularity at that point. $z^{0.5}$ is not analytic at $z=0$ yet it does not have a pole at that point.

Comment: In that case, multiplying by $z$ doesn't produce analyticity at $z=0$, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because $\sin k\pi=0$ giving $$z\cot z=\frac{z\cos z}{\sin z}=\frac{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\cdots\right)}{z\left(1-\frac{z^2}{3!}+\frac{z^4}{5!}-\cdots\right)}=\left(1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\frac{z^4}{4!}-\cdots\right)\left(1+\frac{z^2}{3!}-\frac{z^4}{5!}+\cdots\right)$$ so $z=k\pi$ is a pole of order one, or a simple pole.